# Hamiltonian approximation of the Coulomb interaction energy of two charged oscillators

Tags: homework-and-exercises, harmonic-oscillator, hamiltonian, coulombs-law, approximations

I'm adding an excerpt from the book [*Introduction to Solid State Physics 7th edition*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introduction_to_Solid_State_Physics) by Charles Kittel.
[image]

I don't see how they arrived at the approximation of the Hamiltonian (2) by expanding it. If $x_1$ and $x_2$ are much smaller than $R$ then shouldn't all the terms have $R$ as a denominator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go:

\begin{align}
\mathcal{H}_1&=\frac{1}{R}+\frac{1}{R+(x_1-x_2)}-\frac{1}{R+x_1}-\frac{1}{R-x_2}\\
&=\frac{1}{R}\left(1+\frac{1}{1+(x_1-x_2)/R}-\frac{1}{1+x_1/R}-\frac{1}{1-x_2/R}\right)\\
&=\frac{1}{R}\left(1+1+(x_1-x_2)/R+(x_1-x_2)^2/R^2-(1+x_1+1-x_2)/R-(x_1^2+x_2^2)/R^2\right)\\
&=-2x_1x_2/R^3+\mathcal{O}(1/R^4).
\end{align}

Comment: On the third line did you expand using multi-variable taylor series?

Comment: Nope, just a bunch of geometric series. One in $(x_1-x_2)/R$, one in $x_1/R$, and the last int $x_2/R$.

Comment: Which geometric series, could you add a link for reference?

Comment: Nevermind, I remembered what you meant.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to @BRT's answer, we can first take $1/R$ outside:

$$H_1 = \frac{e^2}{R} \left( 1 + \frac{1}{1+(x_1-x_2)/R} - \frac{1}{1+x_1/R} - \frac{1}{1+x_2/R}\right)$$

Since $R$ is much larger than $x_1$ and $x_2$, we can do Taylor expansion on the 2nd, 3rd and 4th terms in the bracket to the second order:

$$\frac{1}{1+(x_1-x_2)/R} = 1 - \frac{x_1 - x_2}{R} + \frac{(x_1 - x_2)^2}{R^2}$$

$$\frac{1}{1+x_1/R} = 1 - \frac{x_1}{R} + \frac{x_1^2}{R^2}$$

$$\frac{1}{1+x_2/R} = 1 - \frac{x_2}{R} + \frac{x_2^2}{R^2}$$

Adding these expansion terms together and inserting them to the first equation, we get the answer

$$H_1 = - \frac{2 e^2 x_1 x_2}{R^3} $$